# How can I publish a standard ArcGIS basemap on local server?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there a way to publish/install a standard basemap (topo, streets, etc.) to a local ArcGIS server?

I have an app using the javascript API, that is running in an environment that cannot connect to arcgisonline or internet in general so standard basemaps aren't loaded.

Comment: I had seen that before posting the questions here.  It doesn't really explain how to publish/install a basemap like the topo to a local ArcGIS server.  I tried downloading this http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d5e02a0c1f2b4ec399823fdd3c2fdebd and from ArcMap tried to publish as service but I get the error "Basemap Layers cannot be published directly to a service", so I assume there must be another way to install the basemap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Configure a disconnected deployment - Basemaps](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/linux/configure-a-disconnected-deployment.htm):

> The ArcGIS Enterprise portal comes preconfigured with a collection of
>   basemaps from ArcGIS Online. These basemaps are not supported for use
>   in a disconnected environment. Instead, create your own custom
>   basemaps and configure the portal to offer these basemaps in the
>   basemap gallery. See [Customize basemaps](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/customize-basemaps.htm) for details.

If you really want the actual basemaps and do not want to create your own, the [Data Appliance for ArcGIS](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/data-appliance/overview) might be what you need. More information here: [FAQ: Can basemaps be used without an internet connection?](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012114)